# Convert a Uri into a non-Uri android

Tags: android, file, parsing, uri, converters

I have a path like this:

content://media/external/audio/media/7181

That was obtained like this `String mSelectedPath = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + "/";` 
 and then I append the song id to this.

I want to convert it into a path such as /mnt/sdcard/..

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's media database stores the path to files in the `DATA` column. You can read that via

```
long id = 7181;
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder = null;
Cursor c = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
String path = null;
if (c != null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        path = c.getString(0);
    }
    c.close();
}
Log.d("XYZ", "Path of " + id + " is:" + path);
```

But like @CommonsWare said it's possible that (especially on future android versions) there is no file you can access or even no path at all, meaning the path you get might be worthless.

Luckily  `ContentProvider` allows you to read data with IO streams if the provider has that feature implemented (IIRC this one does). So you could read the data represented by that `Uri` like in below example.

```
long id = 7181;
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
    is.read(); // replace with useful code.
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.w("XYZ", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w("XYZ", e);
} finally {
    if (is != null)
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignored
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. It is possible that there is no file (e.g., bytes are stored in a BLOB column in a database, the content represents a stream), or the file is in a location that is inaccessible by your process.